# Deleting entire li with a span doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Deleting one entire li doesn't work after I put the fadeOut function.After I click the span(x) it should remove the li but after I inputed the fadeOut function it doesn't work.

```js
//Check off specific Todos By Clickin
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

//Click on X to delete Todo
$("span").click(function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#container {
    width:360px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:2px solid grey;
}

.completed {
    color:gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/todos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
        <input type="text">

        <ul>
            <li><span>X</span> Go to Potions Class</li>
            <li><span>X</span> Buy New Robes</li>
            <li><span>X</span> Visit hermione</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/todos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `span` or the `li`? Your current code removes the `li` and it works https://jsfiddle.net/5ws03h1m/

Comment: it's working fine for me

Comment: while editing your snippet, turn out it works fine. Maybe missing jquery on source

Comment: replacing the source of jQuery with a cdn it works but with that jQuery source it doesn't

Comment: So... what's the issue here?  You're not including jquery properly?

Comment: In your example why do you include jQuery 2.1.1 from a CDN and then jQuery 3.3.1 slim locally?

Comment: Have a read of: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/   Then add `$(function() { alert("jquery ok"); }` - do you get that alert?

Comment: @j08691 someone edited to add jquery correctly so that the snippet works.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I get the alert

Comment: Ok - the two jquery's are jquery2.1.1 (works) and jquery-3.3.1-*slim* (doesn't work).  So the issue is that it works with **full** jquery but not **slim** jquery - so what's slim missing?  Animations (ie `fadeOut`).

Comment: Fix: don't use the slim version of jquery

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah that was the problem.Thank you.